# not able to source setup.bash after installing ros kinetic on ubuntu-16.04

Tags: linux

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed [this installation guide](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu). I didn't get any error while installing.

but `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` throw error

`/opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash:.:8: no such file or directory: /home/praveen/catkin_ws/setup.sh`

I get similar error in catkin workspace
`source devel/setup.bash` throw `devel/setup.bash:.:8: no such file or directory: /home/praveen/catkin_ws/setup.sh`

when running this command inside devel dir. it returns

```
praveen@praveen ~/catkin_ws/devel
 % source setup.bash 
/opt/ros/kinetic/etc/catkin/profile.d/05.catkin_make.bash:67: command not found: complete
/opt/ros/kinetic/etc/catkin/profile.d/05.catkin_make_isolated.bash:65: command not found: complete
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/rosbash/rosbash:961: command not found: complete
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/rosbash/rosbash:962: command not found: complete
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/rosbash/rosbash:963: command not found: complete
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/rosbash/rosbash:964: command not found: complete
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/rosbash/rosbash:965: command not found: complete
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/rosbash/rosbash:966: command not found: complete
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/rosbash/rosbash:967: command not found: complete
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/rosbash/rosbash:968: command not found: complete
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/rosbash/rosbash:969: command not found: complete
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/rosbash/rosbash:970: command not found: complete
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/rosbash/rosbash:971: command not found: complete
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/rosbash/rosbash:972: command not found: complete
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/rosbash/rosbash:973: command not found: complete
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/rosbash/rosbash:974: command not found: complete
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/rosbash/rosbash:975: command not found: complete
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/rosbash/rosbash:976: command not found: complete
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/rosbash/rosbash:977: command not found: complete
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/rosbash/rosbash:978: command not found: complete
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/rosbash/rosbash:979: command not found: complete
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/rosbash/rosbash:980: command not found: complete
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/rosbash/rosbash:981: command not found: complete
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/rosbash/rosbash:982: command not found: complete
/opt/ros/kinetic/etc/catkin/profile.d/20.transform.bash:23: command not found: complete
/opt/ros/kinetic/etc/catkin/profile.d/20.transform.bash:42: command not found: complete
```

```
echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
```

outputs
`/opt/ros/kinetic/share`

```
% cat /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# generated from catkin/cmake/templates/setup.bash.in

CATKIN_SHELL=bash

# source setup.sh from same directory as this file
_CATKIN_SETUP_DIR=$(builtin cd "`dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"`" > /dev/null && pwd)
. "$_CATKIN_SETUP_DIR/setup.sh"
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248431/not-able-to-source-setup.bash-after-installing-ros-kinetic-on-ubuntu-16.04/) by [prrraveen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21441/prrraveen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2016-11-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-19**:
Did you have a from-sources installation before you installed from debians? Especially this:

> /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash:.:8: no such file or directory: /home/praveen/catkin_ws/setup.sh

is suspicious. Files in `/opt/ros/$distro` should not refer to files in your $HOME.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-19**:
Can you add the contents of `/opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` to your question?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-11-19**:
The many warnings about `complete` not being found makes it seem like you're not using bash. Are you using some other shell like csh or zsh?

**Comment by [prrraveen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21441/prrraveen/) on 2016-11-19**:
Yes, I am using zsh. I suspect that is causing issue. I will try in normal bash shell and let you know. Thanks

**Comment by [prrraveen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21441/prrraveen/) on 2016-11-19**:
I tried it in normal shell. I am getting same error.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-20**:
Do you still get errors if you use `setup.zsh`?

**Comment by [prrraveen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21441/prrraveen/) on 2016-11-20**:
@gvdhoorn. setup.zsh seems working. it is not giving any error. Could you please write an answer so I can mark as correct answer. Hopefully explaining the underline issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're using `zsh` as your shell, you should source the `setup.zsh` file, **not** `setup.bash`. The two files are only compatible with their respective shells.

Edit: strangely enough, the Indigo installation documentation explicitly mentions this (under [Environment setup](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/DebEnvironment)), but the Kinetic instructions didn't. I've added it in [kinetic/Installation/DebEnvironment?action=diff&rev2=3&rev1=2](http://wiki.ros.org/action/info/kinetic/Installation/DebEnvironment?action=diff&rev2=3&rev1=2)).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3